# Does $\forall |\psi \rangle, \langle \psi | A | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | B | \psi \rangle \Rightarrow A=B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Consider two unitary operators $A$ and $B$ acting on a Hilbert space.

Let's assume that $\forall |\psi \rangle$ (vector living in this Hilbert space), we have: $\langle \psi | A | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | B | \psi \rangle$.

I am almost sure that it implies $A=B$, but I do not remember how to show it simply.
Am I correct? How can it be easily derived?

Comment: The answer depends on whether the underlying field is $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$. Do you have such a restriction?

Comment: Use polarization.

Comment: This post should not have been closed, because of the following remaining question.  On a *real* Hilbert space, $\langle \psi | A | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | B | \psi \rangle$ for all $ | \psi \rangle$ does *not* imply $A=B$ in general. But does it imply $A=B$ under the additional assumption that $A$ and $B$ are unital? (I doubt it but have no counterexample). @anomaly